# prevent services without a constraint to run on certain workers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We have a docker swarm with a set of workers and are looking at adding a few dedicated workers with GPU capabilities for some computational work. Currently we do not use constraints, so we have dozens of services already running without constraints.

Is it possible to add nodes to a swarm and prevent tasks being scheduled on them UNLESS they have a specific constraint?  Or to flip that around, is there some kind of default constraint we could remove from a host?